# Query response incorrect

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I got the following Query:

```
SELECT ID, bKey, firstname, lastname, deleted
FROM `tb_user`
 WHERE tb_group_ID = 3 OR tb_group_ID = 4 AND deleted IS NULL
```

Which is giving me this Output:

As you can see, even if the Query says `deleted IS NULL` it still shows the Row where deleted = 1. The other Filters are working without any problems.

So how can I make it work right, without the unwanted Row?

I already tried diffrent methods (like deleted <> 1) but with the same Result.

Comment: Learn to use parentheses.  Or even `in`.

Comment: You query is the same as `... WHERE (tb_group_ID = 3) OR (tb_group_ID = 4 AND deleted IS NULL)`

Comment: AND has a higher precedence then OR.. you need to keep that in mind https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html.. so you need to use parentheses to enforce precedence  `WHERE ( tb_group_ID = 3 OR tb_group_ID = 4 ) AND ( deleted IS NULL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
WHERE tb_group_ID IN (3, 4) AND deleted IS NULL
```

Comment: @E.Reutlinger . . . Because your `where` clause is (tb_group_id = 3) or (tb_group_id = 4 and deleted is null)`.